# Stargazer() does not fit the page

Tags: r, latex, stargazer

Good afternoon, I was trying to find the answer to such question, although there is no information. The point is that I want to put the output of my models (3 models) in the latex file. Although, when I do such thing using stargazer() it leads to 2 problems - first, when I want to show 3 models or more the resulting table does not fit on the page, in particular - going to the right so far, second, when I have many variables, it does not fit the page as well so many variables are not shown. How to deal with it?

```
 \usepackage{dcolumn} 
 \begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
 \caption{Results} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lD{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} } 
  \\[-1.8ex]\hline 
 \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\ 
\cline{2-3} 
\\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{2}{c}{log(Price)} \\ 
\\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{OLS}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}
 {\textit{panel}} \\ 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{linear}} 
 \\ 
 \\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}\\ 
 \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 Coll & 0.513^{***} & 0.019 \\ 
 & (0.028) & (0.039) \\ 
 & & \\ 
 Constant & 0.110^{***} &  \\ 
 & (0.038) &  \\ 
 & & \\ 
 \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 Observations & \multicolumn{1}{c}{14,727} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{14,727} \\ 
  R$^{2}$ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.256} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.011} \\ 
  Adjusted R$^{2}$ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.255} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.341} \\ 
  Residual Std. Error & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.297 (df = 14699)} &  \\ 
  F Statistic & \multicolumn{1}{c}{187.710$^{***}$ (df = 27; 14699)} & 
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{14.477$^{***}$ (df = 8; 10868)} \\ 
  \hline 
  \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
  \textit{Note:}  & \multicolumn{2}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; 
  $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\ 
  \end{tabular} 
  \end{table}
```

Here I basically provide a sample with only 2 models with less variables (just for convenience), however, when I use all of them it does not fit the page.

Answer (score 4):

Try wrapping the `tabular` part inside `scalebox`. So it would be something like:

```
 \begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
 \caption{Results} 
  \label{} 
\scalebox{0.85}{
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lD{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} } 
  \\[-1.8ex]\hline 
 \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\ 
\cline{2-3} 
\\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{2}{c}{log(Price)} \\ 
\\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{OLS}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}
 {\textit{panel}} \\ 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{linear}} 
 \\ 
 \\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}\\ 
 \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 Coll & 0.513^{***} & 0.019 \\ 
 & (0.028) & (0.039) \\ 
 & & \\ 
 Constant & 0.110^{***} &  \\ 
 & (0.038) &  \\ 
 & & \\ 
 \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 Observations & \multicolumn{1}{c}{14,727} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{14,727} \\ 
  R$^{2}$ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.256} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.011} \\ 
  Adjusted R$^{2}$ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.255} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.341} \\ 
  Residual Std. Error & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.297 (df = 14699)} &  \\ 
  F Statistic & \multicolumn{1}{c}{187.710$^{***}$ (df = 27; 14699)} & 
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{14.477$^{***}$ (df = 8; 10868)} \\ 
  \hline 
  \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
  \textit{Note:}  & \multicolumn{2}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; 
  $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\ 
  \end{tabular} 
}
  \end{table}
```

I set scale to 0.85, but you can play around with it. If the print gets too small and the table still doesn't fit, try using the `longtable` package so you can spread the table over multiple pages.